# Ruby on Rails 5.0.1 missing '_comments.html.erb' partial

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are lots of solutions posted on both stack and google in general for this error, but none of it worked for me, so please don't just c/p some random link where they found solution, unless you really think it could be the solution.

I've created `_comments.html.erb` partial, that is responsbile for adding comments in, `views` folder that looks like this

```
<div class="comment clearfix">
    <div class="comment_content">
        <p class="comment_name"><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
        <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
        <p class="comment_time"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> Ago</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

But when I try to access it from `show.html.erb` I can not. I have form for adding comments and body, but when I press `Submit` button it gives me missing partial error.

The code in `show.html.erb` for comments looks like this:

```
<div id="comments">
            <h2><%= @post.comments.count %></h2>
            <%= render @post.comments %>

            <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
            <%= render 'comments/form' %>
        </div>
```

More concretely, this line is a problem `<%= render @post.comments %>`. I tried different way of rendering, but none of it worked. I don't know if something changed in newer version, or am I missing something terribly, but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: can you please try this `render partial:"comments",locals:{comments:@post.comments}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the file should be singular

```
_comment.html.erb
```

Comment: I wouldn't find that error in this century. Thank you : )